# Re-order methods in a class file to match the associated interface file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

Is it possible in Visual Studio 2008, either with or without Resharper, to re-order methods in a class file to match the order of methods in an associated interface file?  What about the opposite (re-ordering the interface to match the implementing class)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly related to your question, but I use the Resharper window "File Structure" to organize the cs-file of the class. In it, you can drag members up and down and encapsulate them in regions.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely makes it easier to accomplish what I wanted.

Comment: My pleasure. Also, you can put the cursor on a class member within the code view, hold Ctrl-Alt-Shift down for one second and then start moving it with your up/down arrow keys. This also works for individual code lines.